# Bizarre behaviour of Pygame mixed with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, pygame, multiprocessing

I am working on a small project including Raspberry Pi camera. I am using multiprocessing on the PC to perform various tasks and one of them is displaying images in a Pygame window. I have manager to minimize the code suffering the problem. This is the main function, which just creates a `Game` process, runs it and waits for it to end:

```
# main.py

from multiprocessing import Manager

import game


with Manager() as manager:
    namespace = manager.Namespace()

    namespace.done = False

    jobs = [
        game.Game(namespace),
    ]

    for job in jobs:
        job.start()

    for job in jobs:
    job.join()
```

Below is the code of the `Game` class. The state is shared because there will be other processes checking if the program has finished.

```
# game.py
import multiprocessing
import pygame
import time
import sys


class Game(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, the_state):
        super(Game, self).__init__()

        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
        self.state = the_state

    def handle_key_events(self):
        """ Wrapper for handling key events """
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.state.done = True
                return

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.handle_key_events()
            if self.state.done:
                print('exiting PyGame thread')
                pygame.display.quit()
                pygame.quit()
                return
```

The behaviour right now is that it doesn't end on clicking the Pygame's exit button. However, if I comment out the `pygame.quit()` line from `Game`'s `run` method, it gives me the following message:

```
exiting PyGame thread
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 120 requests (120 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
```

I tried googling that error but little success. I can't shake off the feeling that I'm attempting something I shouldn't be, considering that probably the Pygame's window is a process on its own.

I would appreciate some insight and recommendations on where to read up

Comment: I've never tried what you're doing, but I'd guess the issue has to do with where `pygame.init` is getting called. I think it will be called in the main processes when it constructs the `Game` instance, and not in the child process (which only spins up when `start()` is called). Try moving the `pygame.init` and `pygame.display.set_mode` calls to the top of `run` and see if that works.

Comment: I seem to recall pygame not being able to handle multiprocessing or threading at all.

Comment: @Blckknght this seems to have solved this issue

Comment: Please answer in answers, not in comments

Answer (score 0):

As Blckknght suggested, the issue was that the parent process (`main.py`) initiated PyGame's window, while the child process (`game.py`) attempted to `quit` it. It can be resolved by moving this part:

```
    pygame.init()
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
```

into `Game`'s `run` method